# How to parse a string to DateTime

Tags: c#

i have a string date in the following format

```
 Thu Jan  5 19:58:58 2012
```

I need to parse this string to `System.DateTime` `TimeReceived` variable using `DateTime.Parse()` method.

Any one knows how to parse this string?

Comment: You just want the time part? What have you tried so far?

Comment: please show some code... what have you tried ? what didn't work ?

Comment: Look into `DateTime.ParseExact` and `TryParseExact`. Many questions exist here that concern those two methods.

Comment: i need it in this format "19:58:58 05/Jan/12"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method which allows you to specify a format:

```
var str = "Thu Jan 5 19:58:58 2012";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // the date was successfully parsed, you could use the date variable here
    Console.WriteLine("{0:HH:mm:ss dd/MMM/yy}", date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) function, about halfway there's

```
dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
```

so if you'd switch those around to match what you want, you'll end up with

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

// Parse date and time with custom specifier.
dateString = "Thu 5 Jan 19:58:58 2012";

format = "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy";
try {
   result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Comment: oh, did not see that parameter. Fixed the code, its just CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Answer (score 0):

```
var reformatted = input.Substring(4, 17) + input.Substring(22);
return DateTime.Parse(reformatted);
```

That should work fine.